# NullPointerException on setting date from Notes document

Tags: java, xpages, lotus-domino

I am getting the following nullpointer exception in my code:

```
fieldName = "created";
Date startDate; 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(this.dtFormatShort);
startDate = df.parse(doc.getCreated().getDateOnly() + " " + doc.getCreated().getTimeOnly()); //here I get the error
customer.setCreated(startDate);
```

I am using similar code across my app but there I do not nullpointer exceptions.

is the error related that I am not calling the constructor for the Date object first? and why does the exception not occur on other places of my app?

Comment: It's not related with not calling the constructor ;) No one will be able to tell why it does fail only in this place. If the NullPointer is thrown in `parse` line, the most probable cause is `doc` or one of its fields being null.

Comment: of course I have checked if doc is not null.

Comment: Is it a saved document? Or an in-memory document?

Comment: saved documents

Comment: When I look at the customer object and investigate at the created field via debugtoolbar I see that the field has a correct value e.g. java.util.Date
toString: Wed Oct 02 13:48:00 CEST 2019

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure why you’d get an NPE there (maybe the date format isn’t set), but you should be able to do something like `doc.getCreated().toJavaDate()` directly and save yourself the parsing headache.

Comment: well in the specs customer was not interested in the seconds that is why may formatter is yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm

Answer (score 0):

A Java constructor cannot return `null`. It either returns a non-null value or throws an exception. Therefore, `df` is not null.

The only other option is that either `doc` or `doc.getCreated()` are `null`. Either that or you've found a bug in the JVM.

P.s. calling the constructor for `Date` before reassigning it should do nothing w.r.t. a NPE being thrown in this code. But if you seriously think it's a JVM bug no harm in testing :)

Comment: of course I have checked if doc is not null. same code when running in dev environment does not result in error. same version of Domino, FP etc